# MVC find record in database using context

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have am ActionResult in my controller that I'm attempting to call with AJAX.get that needs to find a record in the database and return a Json containing some values:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetBranchHead(int branchId = 0)// call this via jquery ajax
    {
        Staff branchHead = (Staff) (db.Staff.Where(o => o.BranchId == branchId && 
                                                        o.StaffTypeId == (int) Mars.Data.Enums.StaffType.BranchHead));

        return Json(new { BranchHeadId = branchHead.StaffId,
            BranchHeadName = branchHead.FirstName,
            BranchHeadSurname = branchHead.Surname },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm not sure if I need to cast it to the type in my model, or how this db context works at all. Should I be using find? BranchId and StaffTypeId are both foreign keys.

Now I call this method from the javascript on my razor page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckSelection() {
    var BranchHeadName;
    var BranchHeadSurname;
    var branchId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetBranchHead?branchId",
        type: "GET",
        data: 1, //$(this).val(),
        success: SetData(BranchHeadName, BranchHeadSurname),
        dataType: JSON
    });
};

function SetData(BranchHeadName, BranchHeadSurname) {
    $("#BranchHeadDisplay").val(BranchHeadName + " " + BranchHeadSurname); //= BranchHeadName + " " + BranchHeadSurname;

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SelectedBranch").change(CheckSelection);
    CheckSelection.apply($("#SelectedBranch"));
});
```

This should call the ActionResult method in my controller whenever a selection in a dropdown box gets changed. (I know I still have to sort out the ajax function, but I'm hardcoding in test data just to test the method)

What I get is the following an internal server error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Mars.Data.Staff]' to type 'Mars.Data.Staff'.

This part is the problem I belive:

```
Staff branchHead = (Staff) (db.Staff.Where(o => o.BranchId == branchId && o.StaffTypeId == (int) Mars.Data.Enums.StaffType.BranchHead));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it something on below lines. Please note if you return JsonResult then it would automatically convert the collection of staff (query) to Json data, which you can retrieve in your success function.

**controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetBranchHead(int branchId = 0)
    {
        var stafftypeid=(int)Mars.Data.Enums.StaffType.BranchHead);
        var query = db.Staff.Where(o => o.BranchId == branchId && o.StaffTypeId == stafftypeid).ToList();

        return Json(query,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**view.cshtml:**

```
function CheckSelection() {
    var BranchHeadName;
    var BranchHeadSurname;
    var branchId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourcontroller/GetBranchHead",
        type: "GET",
        data: {branchId:$(this).val()},
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(data){
         $("#BranchHeadDisplay").val(data.FirstName + " " + data.SurName);
        }       
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

add .single() to your query to select just 1 record

Comment: .single() will return the record if it is unique i.e only one record with the id or values you are searching for. otherwise it will throw an exception if there are no records, or multiple records matching your where criteria. From the question it appears one one record should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var branchHead = db.Staff.FirstOrDefault(o => o.BranchId == branchId && o.StaffTypeId == (int) Mars.Data.Enums.StaffType.BranchHead);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this -

```
var Query = db.Staff.Where(o => o.BranchId == branchId && o.StaffTypeId == (int) Mars.Data.Enums.StaffType.BranchHead).ToList();

if(Query.Any())
{
   Staff branchHead = Query[0];
}
```